# Match multiple values in a regex string with strange formating

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to extract multiple values with a Regex but I am kind of lost.

I should get the result on a named captured group called "value" (used for Grafana)
I am trying to capture one or more variables in a string, not just the first value found.

Got this but doesn't work as expected :

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|.*?\b{?\b)[^}]+?\b(?<value>(\d*?\S))\b
```

Example :

```
{"146":146,"547":547,"179":179,"79":79}
```

I aim to get this result :

```
146, 547, 179, 79
```

Any Regex genius to help ?
Thanx

Comment: The regex might be something like this `(?:\G(?!\A)|{),?"\d+":\K(?<value>\d+)\b` but not sure if that will work in grafana https://regex101.com/r/2GMh2S/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, seeing how [Grafana's documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#filter-variables-with-regex) is referring to Mozilla's guide on regexes in this scope, I can only assume it uses JS engine for this particular functionality. My quick check says that it doesn't support `\K`, but supports lookarounds.

Comment: Also, AFAIK, Grafana doesn't support extraction of multiple values from a single input.

Comment: @markalex Cool, thanks for that. I have seen you answer Grafana questions multiple times, I think this is more your speciality :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks for recognition)) I'm trying to find code responsible for this part, as I was always surprised why JS engine if almost everything else in Grafana's world use RE2, but previously was reluctant to dig deeper.

Comment: I was wrong: Grafana supports multiple values from a single input item, in a classical for JS `/regex/g` way. And it in fact uses JS engine. I'm gathering all the facts for a proper answer. In the mean time, Laurent here is regex you need to use: [`/(?<="\d+":)(\d+)(?=[,}])/g`](https://regex101.com/r/fIetP6/1) (it assumes both keys and values to be numbers). cc @Thefourthbird

Comment: This looks like JSON to me. Get a JSON parser and use it instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Grafana uses JavaScript regex engine for variables. How it is handled inside code can be seen [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/5b63cdb5b0fed1c4c6df879e54b7adb96ac2711c/public/app/features/variables/query/reducer.ts#L105).

For it to provide multiple matches over a single input item, your regex should be wrapped in `/ .. /g`. More on flags in regex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags).

For your example, expression `/(?<="\d+":)(\d+)(?=[,}])/g` should provide expected result. Here:

- `(?<="\d+":)` checks that match is preceded with something matching regex `"\d+":`. If actual keys in your data differs from provided in question example - correct this expression accordingly.
- `(\d+)` matches actual number. Since this is the only capturing group there is no need for naming it.
- `(?=[,}])` checks that match is followed by either `,`, or `}`.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fIetP6/1).

Your own attempt failed due to use of PCRE syntax, which is not supported by JS engine.

Comment: Thanx for the help, it really extract value, but on Grafana i get output only for the first one ( 146 ). Is there a way to get all values in CSV format ?

Comment: @LaurentK, what do you mean? I've tested this regex on Grafana with provided regex, and it parsed all the values: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnjy1.png). What version do you use? Are you sure you provided a correct example of data? Are you sure you copied regex correctly?

Comment: Hey, I'am using Grafana 8.1.8, witch one do you use on your side ?

Comment: @LaurentK, 10.something. The one at play.grafana.org. Please, check provided link to the repo: it could be there were some changes between 8 and 10.